# EditText user input being shown over the top of hint text

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an existing project but that has recently started displaying the edittext wrong on a recent update. I'm not what has changed as this particular part of the app, in the screenshot below, didn't get changed so I'm expecting its some bug in the support libraries but not sure.

Basically the problem is that when the user enters text into an edittext, the hint text doesn't disappear it remains visible as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot showing problem]

Below is the XML code for this particular layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    <ScrollView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/controlContainer"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="vertical" />
    </ScrollView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/noPrimaryKeyInfo"
       android:background="@color/api_error_background"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/no_primary_key_available_therefore_updates_and_deletes_cannot_be_done"
       android:textStyle="bold"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:padding="5dp"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/lblUpgradeStatus"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The EditTexts are then populated programmatically using the following code

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        indexAndFields = (HashMap<Integer, String>) bundle.getSerializable("indexAndFields");
        fieldAndValue = (HashMap<Integer, String>) bundle.getSerializable("fieldAndValue");
        currentTableName = bundle.getString("tableName");

        fieldDataList = rebuildFieldDataListFromJson(bundle.getString("tableAndDescription"));
        Log.d("RowEditor", bundle.getString("tableAndDescription"));
        lblNoPrimaryKeyInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.noPrimaryKeyInfo);

        for (Integer data : fieldAndValue.keySet())
        {
            int index = data;

            FieldData fieldData = getFieldDataFromFieldName(indexAndFields.get(index));

            TextInputLayout textInputLayout = new TextInputLayout(this);

            EditText editText = new EditText(RowEditor.this);
            editText.setHint(indexAndFields.get(index));
            editText.setText(fieldAndValue.get(data));
            if (!purchaseUpgraded)
            {
                editText.setEnabled(false);
            }
            fieldData.setEditText(editText);
            fieldDataList.remove(index);
            fieldDataList.add(index, fieldData);

            textInputLayout.addView(editText);

            if (fieldData.getIsPrimaryKey())
            {
                isPrimaryKeyAvailable = true;
                primaryKeyColumn = indexAndFields.get(index);
                originalPrimaryKeyValue = fieldAndValue.get(data);
                lblNoPrimaryKeyInfo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            controlContainer.addView(textInputLayout);
        }
        //Check if primary key is available, if not, disable all controls and display notification
        disableControlIfNoPrimaryKey();
    }
```

Comment: @SamusArin What you trying to say? Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Which version of the support library are you using? There's a bug in 25.1.0 that causes that for `TextInputLayout`.

Comment: Yep that's the version I'm using. I'll trying upgrading to 25.3.0 see if it fixes

Comment: 25.3.0 has fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a text change listener could provide a quick fix

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if(editText.Text == "")
        {
            editText.setHint(hint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        editText.setHint("");
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a workaround, not an actual fix, the EditText hints used to work

Comment: Yeah, in case you've got a fire to put out from this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As @MikeM mentioned there is a bug in version 25.1.0 of the support library which caused this problem. I updated my gradle.build file to use version 25.3.0 of the support library and this has now rectified the problem.